# Why should I track 'list' parameter on product detail page with Google Analytics enhanced eCommerce?

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, click-tracking

Regarding to [this document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#pal) I *can* send the `Product Action List` with `detail` or `click`.

> The list or collection from which a product action occurred. This is
>   an additional parameter that **can be sent** when Product Action is set to
>   **'detail'** or **'click'**.

But in their (not so) *complete example* they do not use it in Product Action **[detail](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-click)**.

So I guess code should be look like this:

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': <id>,
    'name': <product name>,
    'category': <category name>,
    'brand': <brand name>
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'detail', {list: <list name>});
```

Obviously this list parameter should only be set if the visitor came to this product detail page with a product list click.

I came across this because I have a quite large gap in my product list performance and I do not know why. Round about 25% of my product list clicks have a product list name of `(not set)`.

But all my product list clicks are tracked with a list name. So I do not know why there are 25% `(not set)`.

Since the documentation, I linked above, says that the list information only can be send with action `detail` or `click`, I doubt that it works for `add` (to cart) or checkout. So Google should be able to count the click in product list and view on product detail page to a certain product list.

I guess that I have to rethink about the `add to cart` part of [my answer here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/93185/35905).